# How can I remove the SKU from the compare page in Magento 1.9?

Tags: sku, compare

I'm trying to remove the SKU from the frontend but keep it in the backend. It's used to process orders but it's not something the customer needs to see in this case. All is well except I'm stuck on the compare list page (`site.com/catalog/product_compare/index/`).

In `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml` on line 112 it calls the SKU grouped together with the other attributes:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
```

I'm honestly not sure where to go from here since it's grouped with the other attributes and it's just calling them all :/

Answer (score 3):

The list of attribute which is showing in compare product list depend `on Comparable on Front-end field` **(is_comparable)** of  this attribute ,if `is_comparable` fields is no then it cannot see this compare product list

It manage from `admin>Catalog>Attribute>Manage attribute> click on your attribute to see all the properties of the attribute`.  Here you will find the field `Comparable on Front-end`  which is control on attribute list at compare